# How to selectively display fields in new/edit views with custom form builder in rails 3.2.12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formbuilder

In our rails 3.2.12 app, we would like to selectively display fields in `new/edit` views (using simple_form) based on the access rules. For example, for sales, only customer's `name` and `phone#` can be displayed. Since we don't know what the access rule is going to be, we need to dynamically construct the view at run time. One way to accomplish this is to use `if` in the views and this would make views messy. We thought `custom`form build might help. After reading a few posts online about custom form builder, we still did not have much clue. Can someone provide details about how to implement this with `custom`form builder? Thanks for help!

UPDATE:
Since we don't know what the access rule is going to be, we need to `dynamically` construct `view` at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a custom form builder is used to change the structure of the form's HTML more than to control field access.

A couple of suggestions to "clean up" the views:

1. Using [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) will let you handle form fields/labels as a unit, making it easier to exclude a field using only something like `= form_builder.input :credit_card_number if current_user.admin?`.
2. For a more application-wide solution [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Custom-Actions) can help you manage authorization and roles.

---

Edit:

Based on your comments, it sounds like the following could be a good approach for you if all the columns are treated the same and you don't need to change their order (using HAML, but you could change it to ERB if necessary):

```
= simple_form_for @model do |f|
   = f.error_notification
   - @model.columns_available_for(current_user).each do |column|
      = f.input column
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that we are using simple_form. We have built our own authentication module. As we understood, CanCan does not do column level authentication.

Comment: I see. You can make CanCan do a kind of column level authentication with custom actions (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Custom-Actions), but it sounds like that won't really improve things in your case. Since you're already using SimpleForm, you could consider adding an `accessible_columns_for_role` method to your model (returning an array of symbols), and then just have your view loop through that, calling `simple_form_builder.input` for each one.

Comment: And actually, attr_accessible already supports an ":as => :role" option, so you could potentially find a way to read those options in a view loop.

Comment: The loop through and calling simple_form_builder.input is an interesting idea. There is a method in our app to return an array of column names allowed based on access rule. Since we can not predicate which column would be allowed, we need to dynamically construct the view at run time. We would love to see example if you happen to know some. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rails helpers to do that.

For ex.

```
module SalesHelper  
 def show_fields  
  if current_user.admin?  
    render 'some_partial' #having name and phone field  
  else  
     render 'other_partial'  
  end  
 end
```

end

In your views add respective partials and from new or edit just call
    <%= show_fields %>

Comment: Interesting! Helper is going to make view cleaner.

Comment: Since we don't know what the access rule is going to be, is there a way we can dynamically construct view at run time?